# How to prove that if the moduli of the solutions to $x^2+px+q^2$ are equal, then $\frac pq$ is a real number?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $p$ and $q$ be complex numbers (whereby $q\ne0$). How do I prove that if the moduli of the solutions to $x^2+px+q^2$ are equal, then $\frac pq$ is a real number?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have a $g$ in your equation and not a $q$ or is it a typo?And did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we write $x=qz$, then

$$x^2+px+q^2=0\implies z^2+{p\over q}z+1=0$$

(since $q\not=0$).  If the roots $x_1=qz_1$ and $x_2=qz_2$ have equal moduli, then so do $z_1$ and $z_2$, in which case $z_1z_2=1$ implies $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex conjugates (on the unit circle).  This in turn implies $-{p\over q}=z_1+z_2$ is real.

Answer (score 1):

Any quadratic with two roots of equal modulus can be factorised as:

$$x^2+px+q^2=(x-r\exp(i\alpha))(x-r\exp(i\beta))$$

for some $\alpha, \beta\in[0,2\pi),r\ge0$. Then:

$$p=-r((\exp(i\alpha)+\exp(i\beta)),q^2=r^2\exp(i(\alpha+\beta))$$

Thus, we see:

$$\frac{p^2}{q^2}=\frac{(\exp(i\alpha)+\exp(i\beta))^2}{\exp(i(\alpha+\beta))} = \exp(i(\alpha-\beta))+2+\exp(i(-\alpha+\beta))=2(1+\cos(\alpha-\beta))=4\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^+$$

So, $p/q$ squares to a nonnegative real number, and thus must be real itself

($r=0$ runs into some troubles with this proof, but this is ignorable due to the fact that $q\neq0$)

Answer (score 0):

Let the roots be $z_1,z_2$ with $|z_1|=|z_2|$. If either root is $0$ then $z_1z_2=q^2=0$ which contradicts the premise $q \ne 0$. Otherwise, let $u=\frac{z_1}{z_2}$. It follows that $|u|^2=1=u \bar u$ so $\bar u =\frac{1}{u}$. Then from Vieta's:

$$
\frac{p^2}{q^2} = \frac{(z_1+z_2)^2}{z_1 z_2} = \frac{z_1}{z_2} + \frac{z_2}{z_1} + 2 = u + \frac{1}{u}+2 = u + \bar{u}+2 = 2 \operatorname{Re}u + 2
$$

The RHS is non-negative since $|u|=1 \implies \operatorname{Re}u \ge -1$ so $\frac{p}{q} = \pm \sqrt{2 \operatorname{Re}u + 2}$ is a real number.

Comment: FYI you can ignore the case of roots being $0$ because OP stipulates $q\neq0$.

Comment: @πr8 Thanks. You are right, I reworded that part.